# trying to use clamp_ip to keep sprites onscreen - pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a game for class and this is what we've learned to do so far. I'm trying to get the sprites to stay onscreen with clamp_ip, but it keeps giving me an error message that "Butterfly instance has no attribute clamp_ip." Is there a different way I should be keeping the butterflies onscreen?

This first bit is just setting up pygame and the butterfly class (where I included a line to define a rectangle for the butterflies), I've highlighted where I'm guessing the potential errors are below.

This should be ok.

```
pygame.init()
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

playground = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Butterflies')
screenRect = playground.get_rect() 
steps = 1

class Butterfly: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH)
        self.y = random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        self.image_Butterfly = pygame.image.load('butterflya.png')
        self.image_ButterflyB = pygame.image.load('butterflyb.png')
        self.height = self.image_Butterfly.get_height()
        self.width = self.image_Butterfly.get_width()
        self.rect = (self.width, self.height)  

clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
fps = 10
net = []

for i in range (15):
    butterflyInstance = Butterfly()
    net.append(butterflyInstance)

playground.fill(cyan)
Game_Over = False

while not Game_Over:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Game_Over = True
```

This is where I'm guessing I messed up. I tried to use the clamp_ip function at the end of this loop

```
    for butterflyInstance in net:
        butterflyInstance.x += random.randint(-10, 10)
        butterflyInstance.y += random.randint(-10,10)
        if steps % 2 == 0: 
            playground.blit(butterflyInstance.image_Butterfly, (butterflyInstance.x, butterflyInstance.y))
            steps += 1
        else: 
            playground.blit(butterflyInstance.image_ButterflyB, (butterflyInstance.x, butterflyInstance.y))
            steps +=1 
        butterflyInstance.clamp_ip(screenRect)
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: btw: keep butterfly images on list (`images`) and then you can blit `images[steps]` and change step `steps = (steps + 1) % 2` inestead of `if steps % 2 == 0: ... else ...` - see my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615877/sequential-image-presentation-in-pygame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See PyGame doc [pygame.Rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

`clamp_ip` is `pygame.Rect` method so you have to use  `butterflyInstance.rect.clamp_ip()`

But you have to use `self.rect.x`, `self.rect.y`, `self.rect.width`, `self.rect.height` instead of `self.x`, `self.y`, `self.width`, `self.height` to keep position and size of object.

And use `butterflyInstance.rect.x`, `butterflyInstance.rect.y`, `butterflyInstance.rect.width`, `butterflyInstance.rect.height`
instead of `butterflyInstance.x`, `butterflyInstance.y`, `butterflyInstance.width`, `butterflyInstance.height`

PyGame use `pygame.Rect` in many places - it is usefull. For example: you can use `rect.right` instead of `rect.x + rect.width`, or `rect.center = screenRect.center` to center object on screen.

Comment: Now I am getting new error, "butterfly instance has no attribute 'rect'." I am fairly sure I made all of the changes, I set up the new variable self.rect to equal (self.rect.x, self.rect.y, self.rect.width, and self.rect.height) and I also changed the lines where I blit the butterflies onscreen so that it calls for butterflyInstance.rect.x or y, are there other places you think I should make changes?

Comment: Oh, error is appearing in line where I had self.rect = (self.rect.x, self.rect.y, self.rect.width, self.rect.height). If it helps, I changed this line so it went back to having things like self.x and self.y, without the .rect, and the error changed to "'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'"

Comment: you create `tuple` but `pygame` needs `pygame.Rect()` instance - use `self.rect = pygame.Rect( self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height )` and then use only `self.rect.x`, `self.rect.y`, `self.rect.width`, `self.rect.height` in class, and  `butterflyInstance.rect.x` (etc.) outside  class.

Comment: By the way: you could use shorter name for `butterflyInstance` ;) We use CamelCase names for classes - like `Butterfly` (even Stackoverflow Editor knows this and use blue color for class names - and it thinks `Game_Over` is a class name) and lower_case names for variables, functions, class instances - for example `butterfly`. You don't need postfix `Instance` in variable name.

Comment: by the way: if you already have class `Butterfly` you could create class methods to draw Butterfly, to set random position, and then you could use `butterflyInstance.set_random_position()`, `butterflyInstance.draw(screen, screen_rect)`, etc.